# WCF Socket Timeout Exception while carrying large data

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, sockets

I am working newly on webservice WCF, and I have been assigned a responsibility to test the webservice in case of large data. So, through `Entity Object` I am carrying approx. of 16000+ records, but my code is throwing exception like:

**The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:24:59.9989991'.**

Although I have increased the `Socket Timeout` from **5 To 25** in my `App.Config and Web.Config` files, but still there is the same error. This made me believe that there must be large data issue.

**App.Config**

```
<bindings>  
  <netTcpBinding>  
    <binding name="tcpBinding"  
              maxBufferSize="2147483647"  
              maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"  
              maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"  
             receiveTimeout="00:06:00" sendTimeout="00:06:00" >  
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" />  
      <security mode="None" />  
    </binding>  
  </netTcpBinding>  
  <webHttpBinding>  
    <binding name="RESTBinding"  
              maxBufferSize="2147483647"  
              maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"  
              maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"  
             receiveTimeout="00:06:00" sendTimeout="00:06:00" >  
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" />  
      <security mode="None" />  
    </binding>  
  </webHttpBinding>  
</bindings>
```

**cs file**

```
userObject = client.GetAll().ToList();
```

And, `GetALL()` has this definition:

```
var result = (from user in entity.User select user).ToList();
    return result;
```

And, the above code returns 16000+ records, but due to which webservice is giving exception.
I have done R&D on the topic from the net but don't find any useful answer, can anyone suggest me what should I do.

Comment: `Local socket timeout was '00:24:59.9989991'.` It looks like 25 isn't long enough.

Comment: Well the double `ToList()` probably isn't helping either...

Answer (score 0):

A good decision would be breaking your large data into smaller packages.

Comment: can you please explain how can i achieve it

Answer (score 0):

Modify the API to "page" the results.  In other words, instead of `GetALL()` expose `Get(int start, int end)` and have the user go through them a chunk at a time.  Your code in `GetALL` would change to something like:

```
var result = (from user in entity.User select user).Skip(start).Take(end-start).ToList();
    return result;
```

It's also a nicer thing to do for your users so you don't overwhelm them with too much data.

Comment: thanks for you prompt reply, and sorry for getting back to you so late, i am doing this as a stress testing, for the future reference when my entity will have to go through big chunk of data, so, thats why i selected all records, and can you please explain what will `.skip()` and `.Take()` will do, as i am newbie

Comment: and your code throws the error:
`The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'`

Comment: @HarshSharma Here is documentation for [`Skip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357513.aspx) and [`Take`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300906.aspx).  Using them in this way just breaks the set into chunks.  To avoid the error, add the `OrderBy` method and sort on some property of `user`: `(from user in entity.User select user).OrderBy(u => u.Name).Skip(start).Take(end-start)`